# Access of Undefined property? Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I was programming something and when I thought everything was nice and good, Flash throws an error to me!?

At first I was dumbstruck. Then after checking my code, I couldn't see the culprit. So what I did was 'simple it down', and changed it to just a trace statement.

I was still however getting the error. I don't know what is wrong.

```
   package  {

     import flash.display.MovieClip;
     import src.data.DActors;

     public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip {

        public var dActors:DActors = new DActors;

        public function DocumentClass() {
        trace (dActors);
        trace ("Main");
        }

    }

}
```

This is the DActors Class:

```
package src.data 
{
  public class DActors
   {
       public var me:int = 1;

      public function DActors();
       {    
          trace(me);
       }

  }

}
```

Some scope I'm not aware of or something?

Oh, and by the way, it throws that ''me' is not defined'!?

EDIT: Actually, I failed to realize the real problem, why the hell is my constructor not accepting variables!

```
 package src.data 
 {
public class DActors
{
    public var actors:Array = new Array();
    public var dActor:DActor = new DActor();

    public function DActors();
    {   
        actors.push(dActor);
    }

}
```

}

outputs:

1120: Access of undefined property actors.

1120: Access of undefined property dActor.

???? This worries me greatly. Either my eyes are fooling me or I'm missing something very basic.

Comment: @Kolyunya The 'FlashDevelop with Flash CS6 workflow'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function DActors();
```

Constructor function will not end with `;`(semicolon).

Comment: *FACEPALM* Haha. Thanks. I'm just getting used to the 'put your curly brackets after the method name' that I prematurely add semicolons. Can't believe how incredibly stupid that mistake was, I got so wrapped up in all the data structure and inheritance shenanigans that I put out a bat eye on that.

Comment: I think you are novice to as3. cooool.

Answer (score 0):

```
public var dActors:DActors = new DActors;
```

Should be:

```
public var dActors:DActors = new DActors();
```

Comment: If you're using Adobe Flash Pro. Then: FILE -> PUBLISH SETTINGS -> Flash (.swf) [on the left panel] -> EXPAND ADVANCED -> CHECK: PERMIT DEBUGGING.

Comment: Right, still check the permit debugging. Will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Call the constructor properly

```
public var dActors:DActors = new DActors();
```

Comment: Try `this.me` and `this.dActors`

Comment: trace seems to be a static method; 1042: The this keyword can not be used in static methods. It can only be used in instance methods, function closures, and global code.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon after your `DActors` constructor breaks your code.

```
public function DActors();
```

if you change the `DActors` class to this it will work:

```
package src.data
{
    public class DActors
    {
        public var me:int = 1;

        public function DActors()
        {
            trace(me);
        }
    }
}
```